# Get selected value from dynamic dropdown (options generated by javascript to ID)

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, web-applications, getelementbyid

I am trying to get the value of the dynamic dropdown that is selected by the user (not pre-determined). I'm pretty sure I can't use (tried as well)     `document.getElementById("selectSubject").value;` since it has conflicting ID. I cannot use `document.getElementByClass` since I will be using it to add style by CSS.

```
<script> //to generate the dynamic dropdown that is working
var select = document.getElementById("selectSubject");
if (arrayEmail[i] == email){
var opt = arraySubject[i];
var el = document.createElement("option");
el.textContent = opt;
el.value = opt;
select.appendChild(el);
}
<script>


<select id="selectSubject"> //where the dynamic dropdown is show
<option>Choose assigned subject</option>
</select>

  //additional info that may contribute to the problem
 <form>
<input type="hidden" name ="subjectFolder" id="uploadFile">
  <input type="file" name="imageFile">
  <input type="button" value="Upload File" onclick="google.script.run.withSuccessHandler().upload(this.parentNode)">
</form>
```

Additional info is that I am planning to get the value of the dropdown to be used as parameter in `<input type="hidden" name ="subjectFolder" id="uploadFile">` by `using document.getElementById('uploadFile').value = "value of selected option in dropdown"`

**Edit** **Update** I have tried this as well but didn't work

```
var subjects = document.getElementsByTagName("select").getElementById('selectSubject').value;
document.getElementById('uploadFile').value = subjects;
```

** Edit** **Update** I have tried ravishankar chavare's method by doing this but still doesn't work.

```
 var e = document.getElementById("selectSubject");
 var selected_value = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
 document.getElementById('uploadFile').value = selected_value;
```

** Edit** **Update**

```
 var e = document.getElementById("selectSubject");
 var selected_value = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
 document.getElementById('uploadFile').value = selected_value;
 console.log(selected_value);
```

Console only prints "Choose assigned subject" since it is the default selected but when I remove  `<option> Choose assigned subject </option>` the default selected is one of the array values of the javascript based from the dropdown but console cannot print it's value.

Comment: You shouldn't give conflicting `id`. It should be unique

Comment: Yup I'm pretty aware that is why I am asking for other methods to get the selected value in dropdown

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
var select = document.getElementById("selectSubject");
var opt = 'youreemailvalue';
var el = document.createElement("option");
el.textContent = opt;
el.value = opt;
select.appendChild(el);

function SetSelectedValue() {
var e = document.getElementById("selectSubject");
 var selected_value = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
 document.getElementById('uploadFile').value = selected_value;
 alert('value set to uploadfile')
}
```

```html
<select id="selectSubject" onchange="SetSelectedValue();"> 
<option>Choose assigned subject</option>
</select>

 <form>
<input type="hidden" name ="subjectFolder" id="uploadFile">
  <input type="file" name="imageFile">
  <input type="button" value="Upload File" onclick="google.script.run.withSuccessHandler().upload(this.parentNode)">
</form>
```

Following code is working for me

```
var e = document.getElementById("selectSubject");
var selected_value= e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
```

**selected_value**  get the value which is selected by the user

Working Jsfiddle Example Here 
https://jsfiddle.net/0yfdc51g/

Comment: firstly check that dropdown values and text is filling or not

Comment: It does populate my dropdown menu. Also when I try to manually place the value of the dropdown in  document.getElementById('uploadFile').value = "manual_selected_value"; it works

Comment: means currently you are getting the values from menu but when you setting to hidden field its not working if i am right then $("#uploadFile").val(selected_value); try  to print it in console

Comment: yup it only prints Choose assigned subject and cannot print the other generated options from javascript

Comment: i have created a simple jsfiddle where  menu populating through javascrip dyanmically and when user select the item it will automatically set the value to uploadFile check here https://jsfiddle.net/0yfdc51g/

Comment: Mark as correct answer! Thank you adding an onchange function in select and the function code in javascript works.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `document.querySelector`. Use `document.querySelectorAll` if you want to select all `select#selectSubject`

```js
console.log( document.querySelector( 'select[id=selectSubject]' ) );
console.log( document.querySelectorAll( 'select[id=selectSubject]' ) );
```

```html
<div id="selectSubject"></div>

<select id="selectSubject" class="select"></select>
<select id="selectSubject"></select>
```

Comment: By placing a div id of selectSubject it brings the choices outside the dropdown menu as a plain text that is displayed. Also I tried to add class="select" and use document.querySelector it doesn't work as well

Comment: Those are just an example of elements with conflicting IDs and how to get the elements. Can you please include an example of `conflicting ID` that you are facing?

Comment: It's already shown above. selectSubject is the conflicting ID since this is used to get the appended options from javascript to fill the options in select. I also want to get the selected value without reusing it's ID